# Write to HDFS take a long time Spark-Java

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, hdfs

I'm using Spark-Java,

I have the following command write to HDFS (from DataSet):

```
df.write().format("parquet").mode("append").save(path);
```

If I write 75000 records its take 3-4seconds

If I write 80000 records its take a very long time and not finish (Even after 12 hours!),

What can be the problem? Its a partition memory problem?

What can I try change to fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I see this warning in the log:

> Stage x contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB

Sometimes I see in log exception of:

> Java Heap size

*I have 10 partitions

Comment: It could be a lot of things. Could you provide more information? For instance, where are you writing your data, how many partition do you have, do you get exceptions in the logs, warn messages...

Comment: @Oli, See my edit, thanks!

Comment: How do you know you have 10 partitions? Are you repartitioning `df` before writing it?

Comment: df.repartition(n).write().format("parquet").mode("append").save(path);

where `n` can be some number based on size of your dataset. As other people said, it can be a lot of things.

Comment: @ChitralVerma, what does it means "size of your dataset", my dataset contains around 80k records so I need to do repartition with 80k?

Comment: no. it means you need to distribute records equally among all partitions keeping the size of each partition small ~the block size. also there may be a skew in dataset of there are other operations in pipeline resulting in `df`